# Compute eigenvalues of a particular inverse time a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, spectral-radius

I an exercise, I have

$D=\text{diag}(8,\ldots,8) \in R^{10 \times 10}$, $M=\text{pentadiag}_{10}(-1,-1,1,0,0)$ and $N=M^t$.

**I need to compute the spectral radius of the matrix $(M+D)^{-1}N$**

Since $M+D$ is in Hessenberg form, the eigenvalues are easy to compute. I have that the only eigenvalue is $\lambda_1=9$ and therefore $(M+D)^{-1}$ has eigenvalue $\frac{1}{9}$. Also, $\lambda =1$ is the eigenvalue of $N$.

But with this I can't conclude. I think I should use some similarity trasformation, but I don't have any idea.

Any hint will be really appreciated

Comment: What is $\operatorname{pentadiag}$?

Comment: it indicates a pentadiagonal matrixz (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentadiagonal_matrix)

Comment: From direct computation (with Matlab), the spectral radius seems to be approximately $0.132129$. I see no way to get a "nice" exact expression for this answer

Comment: Uhm, with matlab I get 0.1450 honestly

Comment: @andereBen Could you explain what you mean $\text{pentadiag}_{10}(-1,-1,1,0,0)$? I thought that you were saying that, in the notation of the [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentadiagonal_matrix) you linked, that $a_i = -1$ for all $i$, $b_i = -1$ for all $i$, $c_i = 1$ for all $i$, and $d_i = e_i = 0$ for all $i$.

Comment: @BenGrossmann Yes, exactly.

Comment: @andereBen Also, based on the mysterious nature of your previous question, I suspect that there is a chance that they want you to find this answer numerically and submit your script.

Comment: lol yes, it is taken from a numerical linear algebra text, but I was thinking it was something to do by hand :-) $(M+D)^{-1}N$ is the iteration matrix of a linear iterative method

Comment: I checked with matlab again and you were right. In any case, it does not seem as though there is anything clever to be done here by hand.

Comment: @BenGrossmann  Thank you for the check, I definitely agree :-)